# getDuration() gives 0 output for one file in Android App

Tags: android, audio, mediacontroller

My app loads two audio files from database and stores them in an array. User can play any of them by selecting one from radio button group. both are mp3. One is playing fine and it's elapsed and total duration is displaying correctly. But the same functions display 00:00 total duration for other. Seek bar also updates its progress to 100% in this case but the elapsed time is correctly displaying and audio is playing fine. Someone please tell what is the problem? Why this is happening.. and how can I resolve it??

`audio_urdu`'s time is fine.. error is with `audio_eng`.

```
    private void updateView(int i) throws JSONException 
{
    idx=0;
    _imgBtnPlay.setClickable(false);
    _imgBtnStop.setClickable(false);

    JSONObject jObject=null;
    jObject=Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
    audioUrl_eng=jObject.getString("audio_eng");
    audioUrl_urdu=jObject.getString("audio_urdu");

    lbl_tDuration.setText("00:00");
    lbl_cDuration.setText("00:00");
    lbl_loading.setText("Loading audio files...");
    loadAudio(audioUrl_eng);
}

// Loading audio files from URL
private void loadAudio(String url) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mMediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    try
    {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
            }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
}

// Notify when audio is ready to be played
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     audioPlayerList[idx]=mp;
     idx++;
     if (idx == 1)
     {
         audioPlayer = mp;
         lbl_tDuration.setText(mSecToTimer(mp.getDuration()));
         lbl_cDuration.setText(mSecToTimer(mp.getCurrentPosition()));
         updateSeekBar();

         loadAudio(audioUrl_eng);
     }
     if (idx == 2)
     {
         // Enabling the media control buttons
         _imgBtnPlay.setClickable(true);
         _imgBtnStop.setClickable(true);
         rdGrp.setClickable(true);

         lbl_loading.setText("");
         idx = 0;
     }
}

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        // calling search function
        case R.id.imgBtnSearch:
            onSearchRequested();
            break;

        // when play/pause button is tapped
        case R.id.imgBtnPlay:
            if (audioPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                    audioPlayer.pause();
                    _imgBtnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
            }
            else if (audioPlayer!=null)
            {
                audioPlayer.start();
                _imgBtnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause);
                durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);
            }
            break;

        // when stop button is tapped
        case R.id.imgBtnStop:
            audioPlayer.pause();
            _imgBtnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
            resetProgress();
            break;

        default:
                break;
    }

// Updating the seek bar's time after every 100 milliseconds
public void updateSeekBar() 
{
    durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);
}

// Updating the progress of seek bar
private Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        long tDuration = audioPlayer.getDuration();
        long cDuration = audioPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        lbl_tDuration.setText(mSecToTimer(tDuration));
        lbl_cDuration.setText(mSecToTimer(cDuration));

        int progress = (int) getProgressPercentage(cDuration, tDuration);
        _seekbar.setProgress(progress);
        durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

// Converting milliseconds into min:sec format
public String mSecToTimer(long ms)
{
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secString = "";
    String minString = "";

    // Convert total duration into minutes and seconds
    int min = (int)(ms % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60);
    int sec = (int) ((ms % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60) / 1000);

    // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
    if(sec < 10)
        secString = "0" + sec;
    else
        secString = "" + sec;

    // Prepending 0 to minutes if it is one digit
    if(min < 10)
        minString = "0" + min;
    else
        minString = "" + min;

    finalTimerString = minString + ":" + secString;
    return finalTimerString;
}

// calculating the percentage progress of seek bar
public int getProgressPercentage(long cDuration, long tDuration)
{
    Double percentage = (double) 0;
    long cSeconds = (int) (cDuration / 1000);
    long tSeconds = (int) (tDuration / 1000);

    percentage =(((double)cSeconds)/tSeconds)*100;
    return percentage.intValue();
}

// Converting progress of seek bar into time duration in milliseconds
public int progressToTimer(int progress, int tDuration) 
{
    int cDuration = 0;
    tDuration = (int) (tDuration / 1000);
    cDuration = (int) ((((double)progress) / 100) * tDuration);
    return cDuration * 1000;
}

// Reseting the progress of seek bar when stop button is tapped
public void resetProgress() 
{
    audioPlayer.seekTo(0);
    lbl_cDuration.setText(mSecToTimer(0));
    _seekbar.setProgress(0);
}
```

---

I have one audio in English and one in Urdu language. both are in the array `audioPlayerList`. User can select different languages using radio buttons. and `idx` is variable which tells which audio file is to be played. `audio_eng` is on index 0 (`idx = 0`) and `audio_urdu` is on index 1 (`idx = 1`). Audio is selected as `audioPlayer = audioPlayerList[idx]`

code for Radio button selection is this:

```
rdGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
        {
            // Find which radio button is selected
            if (audioPlayer!=null)
            {
                if(audioPlayer.isPlaying())
                    audioPlayer.pause();
                _imgBtnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                resetProgress();

                if (checkedId == R.id.rdEng) 
                        audioPlayer = audioPlayerList[0];
                else if (checkedId == R.id.rdUrdu)
                        audioPlayer = audioPlayerList[1];
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What was the design goal of having your program do such different things depending on the `idx` variable?   This looks like it could cause the problem you are describing.

Comment: Your code which does different things depending on the value of `idx` appears to be the source of your problem - you only try to deal with the duration for one of the two cases.   This makes no sense, you need to entirely re-write that part so the only difference in behavior is that which is necessary for the different language's role in the program.  Independent counting of the prepare callbacks seems risky too - really, you should start over with a clean idea of what you want your program to do.

Answer (score 0):

Duration of your file 'audio_eng' might be less than 1 second. When calculating percentage you convert milliseconds to seconds that results in `0` total length. That's why you get progress bar set to 100% from the beginning (actually, an exception might be thrown in this case - did you check that?).

When calculatng `percentage` try not to convert `xDuration`into `xSeconds` but divide durations themselves in method `getProgressPercentage`.

I couldn't find other reasons why you get such result

Comment: My audio files are always greater then 10 seconds. App is displaying right elapsed time when it is playing audio_eng. For example it displays elapsed time: 00:21 and Total time: 00:00 @CoolSoft